# SFML linker error: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I was able to get [tutorial #1](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/start-vc.php) to compile fine. But I can't get [the 2nd one](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-window.php) to compile.

When you do new -> Project, *maybe one of those settings are interfering?* Pretty sure I did empty project, else console.

What's wrong?
compile error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function
___tmainCRTStartup  C:\...\02-videomode-iterate\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj)    02-videomode-iterate
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\...\Debug\02-videomode-iterate.exe   02-videomode-iterate
```

entire source:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML-tut: 02");

    bool Running = true;
    while (Running)
    {
        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Project settings:

> include dir, lib: dir set correctly.

c++ -> preprocessor -> preprocessor definitions:

> SFML_DYNAMIC

linker -> input

> tried: `sfml-window.lib` and `sfml-window-d.lib` ( visual studio seems to always use debug mode at start? but tutorial #1 only worked when I didn't use -d version.

subsystem:

> /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` flag, the linker will look for a `WinMain` function rather than the conventional `main`. You have two options:

1. Change to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`. You will get an annoying (or perhaps helpful) console window, which you can get rid of with `FreeConsole`.
2. Change `main` to `WinMain` with the following signature:

   ```
   int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow
   );
   ```

   Unless you need to access `argc` and `argv`, this change shouldn't cause too much trouble.

---

Edit: Perhaps this is worth a look too (copied from the second tutorial):

> Under Windows operating systems, you may have created a "Windows
>   Application" project, especially if don't want the console to show up.
>   In such case, to avoid replacing main by WinMain, you can link with
>   SFML_Main static library and keep a standard and portable main entry
>   point.

So, I suppose that boils down to adding `sfml-main.lib` (or similar) to the list of libraries to link with.